# google map api doesn't works with my code

Tags: android, api, google-cloud-platform, maps

i am using an open source to create city guide application

this source code has a backend which use maps api and it use map api inside the code itself .

it was working well in backend and the apk until i had to change the google cloud account and created another apis from new account  .

but now the api which i am using in backend works well , but the another api which i use in source code doesn't works and it shows empty map .

here is the api's setting :

> 1- Application restrictions : android apps 
>   -  i add package name
>   - i add SHA-1
>
> 2- API restrictions Maps JavaScript API Maps SDK for Android Maps
>   Static API

note : i add a payment in my Billing profile .

i think i did all thing right but don't know why it was working and now it doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

i solved it 
the problem happened because i was using SHA-1 for debugging 
when i looked at Logcat i found there is another SHA-1 key i should use for release